# Как сделать фильтрацию постов по категориям в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть список категорий, нужно сделать фильтр по категории, можно с перезагрузкой страницы.
Есть идеи как это можно реализовать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Могу на чистом php `mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM "Имя вашей таблицы" WHERE category = "Здесь название вашей категории" ");`